# Custom Rollup in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

Our customer has a strange requirement. I am not sure if this is feasible in CRM 2011. Currently, the rollup calculation is always performed on the base currency field. For eg: if the rollup field is selected as "Estimated Revenue" from the opportunity, the rollup calculation is performed on the base of the estimated revenue.

Now ,is it possible to change this behavior. i.e instead of using the base currency field, the rollup calculation has to use the actual currency field.

Has anyone ever attempted to write a custom logic for the rollup calculation.

Thanks,
Vikas

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine why you want to do this. Why would you want to add up dollars, yen, escudos and euros in a single figure (like adding apples and watermelons)?

The whole point of fields like estimatedrevenue_base is to get everything in one currency so that you can add them up and get a figure which at least means something.

If you are only using one currency then there is no difference anyway. If using more than one, Base currency is surely the way to go?

Comment: I know its a little strange. Well, the requirement is that ... 1. If all my opportunities are in USD then my Goal Actuals should be the summation of those USD figures. 2. If 2 of the opportunities are in USD and the third is in some other currency (say Euro) then my Goal Actuals should be SUM(USD) + Euro * Exchange rate.

Comment: For 1) the base values and main values would be the same anyway (assuming your system base currency is USD), for 2) that's what the base values achieve - sum(USD converted to USD, plus Euro converted to USD)